# Android performance on programming to the interface

Tags: java, android, performance

Does modern Android devices have any performance difference between

```
List list = new ArrayList();
```

and

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
```

I recall from years ago (>5) that the latter might perform better a virtual table lookup for method calling isn't needed.

Comment: Do you have a reference to your last statement?

Comment: There is a page in the Android SDK that also mentions the "exact type optimization". However, it states that the JIT compiler makes that kind of optimization unnecessary. There are other ways for getting more performance also described here: http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html#Myths

Comment: With the dawn of Dalvik in favour of ART, aren't they moving JIT to AOT and this is important again?

Comment: @MLProgrammer-CiM IIRC ART is AOT + JIT in which the JIT compiler is used at install time. So it's JIT in that it's performed on-device, but it's AOT in which it's not compiled every time the app is ran.

Comment: This sounds like classic premature optimization - unless you're just asking out of curiosity.

Comment: I ran across some existing code that follow this pattern, wanted to know if it's valid to do so